# Getting error even when Keystore password is true. How?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I had created my android game with libgdx in Elipse. I created the keystore and uploaded the file.

Now i have imported the project in Android Studio. And if i try to sign the apk with same alias and password it gives an error in Android Studio.

Error:Execution failed for task ':android:packageRelease'.

> Failed to read key geekydhaval from store "C:\litikeystore": Cannot recover key

And i know that the keypass and alias password are right because whrn i run :

C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin>keytool -list -v -keystore c:\litikeystore -alias geekydhaval -storepass mykeystorepassword -keypass keypassword

it gives me all the details of the key. including SHA1 MD5.

U don't know what is happening here. PLEASE HELP.

Comment: check if your caps lock is on..

Comment: @Kay no it is turned off.

Comment: Use keytool program to change both the passwords and try again..

Comment: I tried ,  but at the time of changing alias password it asks for the old one and gives the error and when i enter the old one which is true.

Comment: I think it is not true, else why would keytool reject it..

Comment: Ur key is in c:\ one c:\users\geekydhaval\Desktop\liti

Comment: @Aadi sorry i edited question again.

Comment: @kay Then why would it accept while performing keytool -list ?

Comment: If the location and password is right in no way it will reject the key!

Comment: You can look into importing your key to a new keystore here: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3779/how-can-i-export-my-private-key-from-a-java-keytool-keystore/3795#3795

Comment: I fount out that keytool -list only requires keypass,alias not alias pass.  So , i might have forgot my alias password. As far as i remember it is what i think it is but can anyone help me further from here , what to do? Please. *cries*

Comment: I Just Accidently remembered mte down you y alias password , i suggest please wrikey and alias passwornd at 5 places in case you forget it. THANK YOU GUYS.